# Why it needs special case when checking if a number is power of 3 using template recursion?

Tags: c++, templates, math, recursion

I try to write template recursion code to check if a number is power of 3:

```
#include <stdio.h>
template<int z>
struct s{
    enum{e=z%3==0?s<z/3>::e:z==1?1:0};
};

int main(){
    printf("%d\n",s<91>::e);
    return 0;
};
```

but cannot compile,for example,for s<91>::e , the compile error is like that:

```
error: no member named 'e' in 's<0>'
enum{e=z%3==0?s<z/3>::e:z==1?1:0};
              ~~~~~~~~^
note: in instantiation of template class 's<0>' requested here
enum{e=z%3==0?s<z/3>::e:z==1?1:0};
              ^
note: in instantiation of template class 's<1>' requested here
enum{e=z%3==0?s<z/3>::e:z==1?1:0};
              ^
note: in instantiation of template class 's<3>' requested here
enum{e=z%3==0?s<z/3>::e:z==1?1:0};
              ^
note: in instantiation of template class 's<10>' requested here
enum{e=z%3==0?s<z/3>::e:z==1?1:0};
              ^
note: in instantiation of template class 's<30>' requested here
enum{e=z%3==0?s<z/3>::e:z==1?1:0};
              ^
note: in instantiation of template class 's<91>' requested here
printf("%d\n",s<91>::e);
```

but after I add template special case s<0> it seems work suddenly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
template<int z>
struct s{
    enum{e=z%3==0?s<z/3>::e:z==1?1:0};
};

template<>
struct s<0>{
    enum{e=0};
};

int main(){
    printf("%d\n",s<91>::e);
    return 0;
};
```

why does this code need template special case? Take 91 as example, I don't understand where the template will reach s<0> because the value of z should be base on division by 3 and should not reach 0.

Also I even don't know why s<91>::e will generate error

```
note: in instantiation of template class 's<30>' requested here
enum{e=z%3==0?s<z/3>::e:z==1?1:0};
```

because 91%3 should not be equal to 0 and it should be jump to z==1 to determine the value of z.

but I take some examples to test it:

```
printf("%d\n",s<3>::e);
printf("%d\n",s<6>::e);
printf("%d\n",s<9>::e);
printf("%d\n",s<11>::e);
printf("%d\n",s<27>::e);
printf("%d\n",s<60>::e);
printf("%d\n",s<81>::e);
printf("%d\n",s<91>::e);
```

and output seems correct:

```
1
0
1
0
1
0
1
0
```

why would it happen?

Comment: *because 91%3 should not be equal to 0 and it should be jump to z==1 to determine the value of z* I thought so too. Hopefully somebody has an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Template instantiations don't short-circuit. Your ternary conditional statement,

```
enum{e = (z%3==0) ? s<z/3>::e : (z==1 ? 1 : 0)};
```

always instantiates `s<z/3>`, irrespective of the value of `z%3`.

As [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/be19f1c81dce55f5) template instantiation trace shows, this is how you get to `s<0>` : `s<91> -> s<30> -> s<10> -> s<3> -> s<1> -> s<0>`.

Answer (score 0):

While I am just as much puzzled by the compiler error message as you are, I think you can make your code a lot easier to to read by using:

```
template<int z>
struct s{
   static const bool e = (s<z/3>::e && z%3==0);
};

template<>
struct s<0>{
   static const bool e = false;
};

template<>
struct s<1>{
   static const bool e = true;
};
```